# Alinhar div no rodapé dentro de outra div

Tags: html, css

Tenho um DIV content que engloba outra chamada Images, gostaria que a a div images ficasse no fundo da div content com um certo espaço que eu poderia definir, ex: 400px, porém isso que acontece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estrutura do código:

```
<div id="content">

<p>TEXTO TEXTO</p>
     <div id="images"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É necessário basicamente definir a div principal com a `position: relative` e a div filha `position: absolute`, o resto é editar da forma que você necessitar. Segue o exemplo:

texto texto texto

```css
  #content {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 150px;
    width: 100px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
  }
  #images {
    position: absolute;
    background: red;
    width: 80%;
    height: 20%;
    bottom: 0;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
  }
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <span>texto texto texto</span>
  <div id="images"></div>
</div>
```